# Try to find a seminorm $p$ on a locally convex space st $|f|\leq p$.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

Let $X$ be a locally convex space. Let $M$ be a linear subspace of a locally convex space $X$. Let $f\in M^*$. Then can we find a seminorm $p$ on $X$ such that $|f(x)|\leq p(x)$ for all $x\in M$?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Isn't $|f|$ a seminorm?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Yes but it is not on $X$.

Comment: Then extend $f$ it to $X$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown But how?

Comment: Any way! As you state the problem, you don't need any sort of continuity.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I am sorry I am a little slow. Can you give me an example?

Comment: As LordSharkTheUnknown noted, the absense of continuity requirements makes all the topological stuff (i.e., local convexity of $X$ and continuity of $f$) useless. Just extend $f$ from $M$ to a linear functional $g$ on $X$ in pure algebraic way and take $p = |g|$. Any "pure algebraic way" depends on the axiom of choice, but essentially boils down to existence of a linear subspace $N$ of $X$ such that $X$ is the direct sum of $M$ and $N$ (and then for $y\in M$ and $z\in N$ we let $g$ be defined by $g(y + z) = f(y)$).

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown what do you think on finding a _continuous_ $p$?

Comment: @metamorphy Is there an analogue of the Hahn-Banach theorem for locally convex spaces?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown this is exactly the reason I've removed the comment I initially put here... drowning in the forgotten ;)